# Ionic with Capacitor removing white screen after splash?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

trying to solve the white screen problem after the splash screen then it loads, how do we remove it? i tried to set timeout but still not working.

with cordova i can set it up but i'm failing using capacitor

Comment: Where exactly do you fail? You should edit your question and explain it and probably show some code. This increases your chances of getting a helpfull answer.

Comment: when the app loads it shows a splash screen then after it shows a white screen before loading the app fully. can you assist?

Comment: As mentioned by @marsh-wiggle, add some code screenshots. Specifically your ngOnInit() method in app.component.ts.. there must be some blocking code which is resulting in the white screen.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

`capacitor.config.json` - on plugins

```js
"plugins": {
            "SplashScreen": {
              "launchShowDuration": 5000,
              "launchAutoHide": true,
              "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP",
              "androidSplashResourceName": "splash",
              "splashFullScreen": false,
              "splashImmersive": false
            }
          },
          "android": {
            "allowMixedContent": true
          }
```

And then in `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` file:

Change the below:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

To:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
   </style>
```

The `launchShowDuration` is probably what you're after. In case you do get an issue with the splash image width being stretched, the xml will solve that...

Comment: According to your method, the status bar is hidden even after splashscreen.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

capacitor for control needed to install the splashScreen plug-in.

This works for me:

```
npm i --save @capacitor/splash-screen
```

capacitor.config.json // .ts

```
"plugins": {
"SplashScreen": {
  "launchShowDuration": 10000,
  "launchAutoHide": false
}}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {SplashScreen} from '@capacitor/splash-screen';
setTimeout(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, 2000);
```

Comment: lol this is just waiting until it finish loading by covering up with a setTimeout :P

Answer (score 3):

You can change the color in `capacitor.config` with `backgroundColor`.

```
{
    "appId": "io.ionic.starter",
    "appName": "app",
    "webDir": "build",
    "bundledWebRuntime": false,
    "backgroundColor": "#ff0000" // <-- here
}
```

You don't need download the extra package "@capacitor/SplashScreen" lol.

*Disclaimers: I'm speaking for Capacitor v3 and Ionic v5*

Comment: Works on Ionic 6 too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Capacitor 3+ / Ionic 5+ / Angular 12+**

This works for me:

*capacitor.config.json*

```
 "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchAutoHide": false,
      "showSpinner": true
    }
  }
```

*app.component.ts*

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

 private initializeApp(): void {
   
    // other code here

    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the above solutions did not work in my case.

What helped me was to launch in production mode:

```
ionic build --prod --release
```

instead of

```
ionic build
```

As soon as the splashscreen ends, the home page appears.
(Ionic / angular / capacitor)